# How to save json response in jmeter?

Tags: java, json, jmeter, web-api-testing, post-processing

Goal: Save the response I am getting from api request to json files.
filename needed: name_of_original_file_request_was_sent_with + "_response.json"
Until now the jmeter program reads like 6 files, takes data from each file and puts it in body while making API request. I get 6 responses. Now How do I save those responses in files?
I used this code but it replaces the original files that I sent request with:

```
new File(vars.get('file')).bytes = prev.getResponseData()
```

Below is response file:

```
{
  "type": "transaction-response",
  "link": [
    {
      "relation": "self",
      "url": "https://someurl.com"
    }
  ],
  "entry": [
    {
      "response": {
        "status": "201 Created",
        "location": "Player/aerear",
        "etag": "1",
        "lastModified": "2020"
      }
    }       
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you basically need to amend your code in order to:

1. Remove extension from the original file
2. Add `_response.json` to it

For point 1 you can use [FileNameUtils.getBaseName()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getBaseName-java.lang.String-) function

For point 2 you can use simple [string concatenation](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-concatenate-strings)

Something like:

```
new File(org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.getBaseName(vars.get('file')) + '_response.json').bytes = prev.getResponseData()
```

should do the trick for you.

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Where does the file gets saved? Can I specify the path?

Comment: In current JMeter's working directory, you can specify the full path instead of relative if you want

Comment: new File(org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.getBaseName(vars.get('file')) + '_response.json').bytes = prev.getResponseData()   In this where do I specify the path? Or is it somewhere in jmeter listener?

Comment: `new File(C:/somefolder/someotherfolder/' + org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.getBaseName(vars.get('file')) + '_response.json').bytes = prev.getResponseData()`